# Uploading CSV when file size is below 10 KB

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 2.3.7. I am going to upload CSV file. If file size is above 10 KB then its working fine.

But below 10 KB it gives `FileNotFoundException`.

Below is code

```
def file = request.getFile("file")
InputStream csv = new FileInputStream(file?.getFileItem().storeLocation);
csv.eachCsvLine { tokens -> 
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939566/reading-single-inputstream-from-multiple-methods try this approach

Comment: where is the exception thrown exactly.  have you verified, that the file is there and contains data etc.