# code throws NZEC(non zero exit code)

Tags: java, primes

This code produces now Non zero exit code now. I googled for NZEC and found that may be the program is throwing some exceptions but according to me every except seems to have been caught. please look into the code for where i am wrong.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class check
{
    public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            InputStreamReader in=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(in);
            int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            String[] input=new String[t];
            int counter=0;
        while(counter<t&&((input[counter]=br.readLine())!=null))
        {
            counter++;
        }
        br.close();
        in.close();
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(input[i]);
            int m=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            int n=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            boolean[] prime=new boolean[n+1];
            for(int j=2;j<=n;j++)
            {
                prime[j]=true;
                prime[1]=false;
            }
            for(int j=2;(j*j)<=n;j++)
            {
                for(int k=j;j*k<=n;k++)
                {
                    prime[k*j]=false;
                }
            }
            for(int j=m;j<=n;j++)
            {
                if(prime[j]==true)
                    System.out.println(+j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e){}



    }

}
```

Comment: Related / possible duplicate - [Reading single InputStream from multiple methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939566/reading-single-inputstream-from-multiple-methods). In short - don't create multiple readers on one input stream (System.in), didn't check whether those you're using actually buffers, but it might be your problem.

Comment: @Dukeling i edited the code as you said but now, the code gives Non Zero Exit Code (NZEC). I seem to have caught every exception i guess. Your inputs may be valuable.